# PHP glob() regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, glob

I have a folder that contains logos for sponsors. In my website, a user can belong to a sponsor and the sponsor_id is set in session when the user logs in.

Here is my code:

```
function sponsor_logos($sponsor_id) {
    $logos = glob("resources/content/sites/{$sponsor_id}*");

    foreach($logos as $logo) {
        if(file_exists("{$logo}"))
            echo "<img src='/{$logo}' />";
    }
}
```

The above works, but a sponsor can have multiple logos. So the multiple logos are saved like so: sponsor_id.jpg, sponsor_id_2.jpg, sponsor_id_3.jpg

I am not the strongest at regex, so any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: You say it works, so what's the problem? `*` should catch all

Comment: `glob()` doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: @jurgemaister - The problem is that if I pass a sponsor_id of say 1, with the above it catches sponsor logos that are named 10.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg, etc.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - What could I use instead of `glob()`?

Comment: I am working on a legacy system so I can't change the names of the files

Comment: So a logo could be named `1.jpg` if the sponsor only has one logo, but `1_1.jpg` `1_2.jpg`etc. if there are multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better open directory and check all files in it (if there are not so much files). You could do it like that:

```
function sponsor_logos($sponsor_id) {
    if ($dh = opendir('resources/content/sites/')) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(strpos($file, $sponsor_id . '.') === 0) {
                $sponsor_files[] = $file;
            }
            else if(strpos($file, $sponsor_id . '_') === 0) {
                $sponsor_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
    foreach($sponsor_files as $logo) {
        echo "<img src='resources/content/sites/" . $logo . "' />";
    }
}
```

But best solution is to have normal naming scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I certainly agree with a normal naming scheme. This seems to be working just fine!

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `sponsor_id(_\d+)?\.jpg`